# Retrieve the default associated file types of an application?

Tags: shell, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

The function `ShellFindExecutable` allows finding the program which is associated with a specific file type:

```
function ShellFindExecutable(const FileName, DefaultDir: string): string;
var
  Res: HINST;
  Buffer: array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ResetMemory(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  Res := FindExecutable(PChar(FileName), PCharOrNil(DefaultDir), Buffer);
  if Res > 32 then
  begin
    // FindExecutable replaces #32 with #0
    for I := Low(Buffer) to High(Buffer) - 1 do
      if Buffer[I] = #0 then
        Buffer[I] := #32;
    Buffer[High(Buffer)] := #0;
    Result := Trim(Buffer);
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

For example:

```
DefProgram := ShellFindExecutable('R:\test.txt', '');
// DefProgram: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

But how can I find the file type(s)/extension(s) for which a specific existing program is the default associated application?

Delphi 10.1 Berlin
Windows 7 x64

Comment: Iterate through each registered extension checking whether the associated application is your target. Also, the juggling with space characters looks utterly bogus.

Comment: "Iterate through each registered extension" seems logical. I was just wondering if there was an explicit function to achieve this. - What alternative would you suggest for "juggling with space characters"?

Comment: I don't believe that FindExecutable does what you claim. Anyway, for a major task like this I'd expect that IQueryAssociations will be the most efficient mechanism.

Comment: I have made extensive tests. In all cases where a default program is associated with a specific existing file, the default program was correctly retrieved.

Comment: Microsoft documentation says: "FindExecutable function: 
Retrieves the name of and handle to the executable (.exe) file associated with a specific document file."

Comment: What you claim is just not true. No sane API would replace space characters with nulls. That can't be true.

Comment: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\source\rtl\win\Winapi.ShellAPI.pas: function FindExecutable; external shell32 name 'FindExecutableW';

Comment: Stop adding random comments.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You state 'I have made extensive tests. In all cases where a default program is associated with a specific existing file, the default program was correctly retrieved.' That may well be true but proves nothing. There will be no embedded nulls in the string, so none will be replaced. In other words your code achieves nothing in practice.

Comment: Everything in the `begin..end` block after `if Res > 32 then` is useless except `result := Buffer;`

Comment: I think @DavidHeffernan and you are not talking about the same, `FindExecutable` does what MSDN claims, but it does not replace #0 with #32, which is what your source code claims. What #0 would there be in a file name? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Thanks to everybody for having me told the truth! Now I have removed the useless code and it seems to still work!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is an API function specifically to do that. You will need to iterate through each registered extension, for instance by enumerating keys in HKCR, and check which executable is associated with the open verb.

Rather than using `FindAssociation` I suspect that `IQueryAssociations` will be more efficient and robust.

Furthermore what you claim about `FindAssociation` replacing spaces with nulls is simply not true. You can replace the body of your `if` statement with `Result := Buffer`.

Comment: Not really. I'm sure you can do this. You just need to iterate over HKCR. You have everything else. It's then an exercise to see if using IQueryAssociations is faster.